# Who is the Best archer in Hindu mythology?

Tags: rama, arjuna, kartikeya

Among all the mahamaharathis,atimaharathis and maharathis , who is the best archer in Hinduism in terms of skill and victories? Was it lord Rama ,Arjuna ,Laksmana , lord Kartikeya , lord shiva ?

Note- I understand that as lord Kartikeya and lord shiva are celestial beings , they cannot be compared to the rest of the three , but among the other three can we know who was superior in skills (not strength) when archery is concerned thank you.

Comment: Also , I forgot to mention Indrajeet . Please include him too in the comparison.

Comment: Among manuṣyas, none can rival Rāma Dāśarathi's skill in dhanurvidyā (even Arjuna Pāṇḍava can't compare to him). Śiva is also foremost in dhanurvidyā, but he is not a manuṣya. There is no need to compare Rāma and Śiva, for both are non-different in svarūpa and are equals in śakti, neither is above or below the other. However, Rāma in his manuṣyarūpa avatāra had put some limitations upon himself (unlike Kṛṣṇa), hiding his īśvaratva. There's also no point in comparing Skanda & Śiva.

Answer (score 1):

Inscription from Narendra (Kadambas of Goa) dated 1125 CE mentions the ideal/best archers in all 4 yugas

1. Krita (Satyuga) - Pinaki Siva
2. Tretayuga - Rama
3. Dvaparyuga - Arjuna (Phalguna)
4. Kaliyuga - Singhana

[image]